# Membership triple in Linked Data Platform Standard

Tags: semantic-web, linked-data, linked-data-platform

Assume the existence of the following LDP resources & their representation:

```
Prefixes:
  dex -> http://example.com/data/,
  schema -> http://schema.org/
```

an LDP RDF Source

```
dex:ParkingFacility a ldp:RDFSource;
    foaf:primaryTopic <#it> .

<#it> a on:ParkingFacility;
    dc:title "Some parking facility" .
```

a direct container

```
dex:ParkingPhotos a ldp:DirectContainer
    ldp:membershipResource <http://example.com/data/ParkingFacility#it>;
    ldp:hasMemberRelation schema:image .
```

Suppose I make a POST request for an LDP-NR to `dex:ParkingPhotos` and the LDP-NR is successfully created with IRI `dex:ParkingPhoto1`, the triple `(dex:ParkingPhotos, ldp:contains, dex:ParkingPhoto1)` will be added as a containment triple in `dex:ParkingPhotos`. The membership triple is `(<http://example.com/data/ParkingFacility#it>,schema:image,dex:ParkingPhoto1)`.

**Where will the membership triple be added?**

I am getting this confusion because in the [LDP standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/ldp/), in Section 5.1, if we follow Example 11, the membership triple should be added in `dex:ParkingFacility`. However, Section 5.1 is non-normative. I have looked in the LDP standard normative sections, I have not seen anywhere which say it precisely where this membership triple should be placed.

Comment: Well, perhaps you could try to ask at [publc-ldp-comments@w3.org](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-ldp-comments/) or [publuc-ldp@w3.org](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-ldp/), contact somebody of the working group members, find something similar in the [test cases](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/ldpwg/raw-file/tip/tests/ldp-testsuite.html), look how known [implementations](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/ldpwg/raw-file/default/tests/reports/ldp.html) work.